# HTML parsing from C#

Tags: c#, html, parsing, hyperlink

I'm trying to parse some HTML files which don't always have the exact same format. Nevertheless, I've been able to find some patterns which are common to all the files.

For example, this is one of the files:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/63908/000006390816000103/mcd-12312015x10k.htm#sFBA07EFA89A85B6DB59920A55B5021BC

I've seen that all the files I need have a unique  tag which InnerText equals to "Financial Statements and Supplementary Data". I cannot search directly for that string as i appears repeatedly along the text. I used this code to find that  tag:

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(m_strFilePath);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
{
    if (link.InnerText.Contains("Financial Statements"))
    {

    }

}
```

I was wondering if there's any way to get the position of this tag in the html substring so i can get the data i need by doing:

```
dataNeeded = html.substring(indexOf<a>Tag);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: If you watch the code, you'll notice that I'm already using HTMLAgility pack

Comment: In addition, the website posted does not have a proper HTML structure